# Overriding HTTP request headers via query string

Tags: asp.net, http-headers, servicestack

We have a client of a ServiceStack service that cannot easily send the correct value for some request headers (such as Accept or Accept-Encoding).

Is there any mechanism in ServiceStack (or ASP.NET) that can allow the client to use query string parameters to override the value of request headers, in a generic way?

The `format` URL param recognized by ServiceStack is close, but it seems to not help in this specific case (the client needs to send `Accept: image/png`, which seems to be ignored by the format param).

Or another way to look at this, is there a way to name or annotate the properties of a GET request DTO so that ServiceStack will populate those properties with the values of request headers during deserialization? This could provide an alternative approach for solving this problem.

Comment: You can't override HTTP Headers, but they're just a source of metadata about the Request. What behavior are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to get ServiceStack to treat the request differently? Can you use a Request Filter to extract queryString params? i.e. Do you just want to change the `IRequest.ResponseContentType` or something else?